How to check if new kernel will be installed with given Nvidia driver version?
How to check if installation of given Nvidia drivers will also include installation of newer kernel? I have tried apt depends nvidia-driver-550 but output does not include any linux-image and yet I know it will be installed. How to find it out beforehand??
6.8.0-40-generic #40~22.04.3-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Jul 30 17:30:19 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Background story:
I have recently switched my graphics card from 760 to 1650 in order to get support for DXVK in v2 which required nvidia drivers > 520 and obvious hw dx12 support. I have installed the newest driver available to me which is of v550. However, that installation also included installation of newer linux kernel linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic which breaks my network connectivity and some other stuff (right now I am on linux-image-6.8.0-40-generic) I was able to boot back to my working kernel version and reinstalled nvidia v470 drivers. This works fine but prevents me from using required DXVK version.
Edit:
This is the apt install nvidia-drivers-550 I did (twice) and kernel is installed indeed. Why??
og started: 2024-09-21  12:06:35
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 251312 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libnvidia-compute-470:i386 (470.256.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-cfg1-550:amd64.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 251297 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libnvidia-cfg1-550_550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-cfg1-550:amd64 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-common-550.
Preparing to unpack .../01-libnvidia-common-550_550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-common-550 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-compute-550:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../02-libnvidia-compute-550_550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-compute-550:amd64 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-compute-550:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../03-libnvidia-compute-550_550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-compute-550:i386 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-decode-550:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../04-libnvidia-decode-550_550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-decode-550:i386 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-decode-550:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../05-libnvidia-decode-550_550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-decode-550:amd64 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-egl-wayland1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../06-libnvidia-egl-wayland1_1%3a1.1.9-1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-egl-wayland1:amd64 (1:1.1.9-1.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-encode-550:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../07-libnvidia-encode-550_550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-encode-550:amd64 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-encode-550:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../08-libnvidia-encode-550_550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-encode-550:i386 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-extra-550:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../09-libnvidia-extra-550_550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-extra-550:amd64 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-fbc1-550:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../10-libnvidia-fbc1-550_550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-fbc1-550:i386 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-fbc1-550:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../11-libnvidia-fbc1-550_550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-fbc1-550:amd64 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-gl-550:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../12-libnvidia-gl-550_550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-gl-550:amd64 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-gl-550:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../13-libnvidia-gl-550_550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-gl-550:i386 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxnvctrl0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../14-libxnvctrl0_510.47.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxnvctrl0:amd64 (510.47.03-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../15-linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic_6.8.0-45.45~22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic (6.8.0-45.45~22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-signatures-nvidia-6.8.0-45-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../16-linux-signatures-nvidia-6.8.0-45-generic_6.8.0-45.45~22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-signatures-nvidia-6.8.0-45-generic (6.8.0-45.45~22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-kernel-common-550.
Preparing to unpack .../17-nvidia-kernel-common-550_550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-kernel-common-550 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-nvidia-550-6.8.0-45-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../18-linux-modules-nvidia-550-6.8.0-45-generic_6.8.0-45.45~22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-nvidia-550-6.8.0-45-generic (6.8.0-45.45~22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-nvidia-550-generic-hwe-22.04.
Preparing to unpack .../19-linux-modules-nvidia-550-generic-hwe-22.04_6.8.0-45.45~22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-nvidia-550-generic-hwe-22.04 (6.8.0-45.45~22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-compute-utils-550.
Preparing to unpack .../20-nvidia-compute-utils-550_550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-compute-utils-550 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-kernel-source-550.
Preparing to unpack .../21-nvidia-kernel-source-550_550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-kernel-source-550 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-utils-550.
Preparing to unpack .../22-nvidia-utils-550_550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-utils-550 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-550.
Preparing to unpack .../23-xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-550_550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-550 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-driver-550.
Preparing to unpack .../24-nvidia-driver-550_550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-driver-550 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-prime.
Preparing to unpack .../25-nvidia-prime_0.8.17.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-prime (0.8.17.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package screen-resolution-extra.
Preparing to unpack .../26-screen-resolution-extra_0.18.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking screen-resolution-extra (0.18.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-settings.
Preparing to unpack .../27-nvidia-settings_510.47.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-settings (510.47.03-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic (6.8.0-45.45~22.04.1) ...
I: /boot/vmlinuz.old is now a symlink to vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic
I: /boot/initrd.img.old is now a symlink to initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic
I: /boot/vmlinuz is now a symlink to vmlinuz-6.8.0-45-generic
I: /boot/initrd.img is now a symlink to initrd.img-6.8.0-45-generic
Setting up libnvidia-compute-550:amd64 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-compute-550:i386 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-prime (0.8.17.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-common-550 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-utils-550 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-fbc1-550:amd64 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-fbc1-550:i386 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-cfg1-550:amd64 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-compute-utils-550 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Warning: The home dir /nonexistent you specified can't be accessed: No such file or directory
Adding system user `nvidia-persistenced' (UID 129) ...
Adding new group `nvidia-persistenced' (GID 137) ...
Adding new user `nvidia-persistenced' (UID 129) with group `nvidia-persistenced' ...
Not creating home directory `/nonexistent'.
Setting up linux-signatures-nvidia-6.8.0-45-generic (6.8.0-45.45~22.04.1) ...
Setting up libxnvctrl0:amd64 (510.47.03-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-egl-wayland1:amd64 (1:1.1.9-1.1) ...
Setting up screen-resolution-extra (0.18.2) ...
Setting up libnvidia-gl-550:amd64 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-gl-550:i386 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-kernel-common-550 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic
Setting up libnvidia-extra-550:amd64 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-kernel-source-550 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-settings (510.47.03-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-decode-550:amd64 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-decode-550:i386 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-550 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-encode-550:amd64 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-encode-550:i386 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up linux-modules-nvidia-550-6.8.0-45-generic (6.8.0-45.45~22.04.1) ...
linux-image-nvidia-6.8.0-45-generic: constructing .ko files
nvidia-drm.ko: OK
nvidia-modeset.ko: OK
nvidia-peermem.ko: OK
nvidia-uvm.ko: OK
nvidia.ko: OK
Setting up linux-modules-nvidia-550-generic-hwe-22.04 (6.8.0-45.45~22.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-driver-550 (550.107.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.8) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic (6.8.0-45.45~22.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
dkms: WARNING: Linux headers are missing, which may explain the above failures.
      please install the linux-headers-6.8.0-45-generic package to fix this.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-45-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-45-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
done
Log ended: 2024-09-21  12:07:21


It never ever will.  3rd party drivers never ever will.  Canonical/Ubuntu adds a new kernel. Nothing to do with a driver. A driver might depend on new features but then you need to add the new kernel 1st yourself if it is not offered during an upgrade, You probably need to upgrade to 24,04 to use your driver

but why when I do apt install nvidia-driver-550 new kernel is installed? Did it twice and twice the same story.

@Rinzwind added installation log. What I did wrong that kernel was installed?

As was mentioned, the kernel got installed via an update. The Nvidia driver messages you see are the attempt to build the driver and an initrd.img which uses it for the kernel. You appear to be missing some headers needed for the build --odd since if you have the metapackages linux-headers-generic, linux-headers-generic-hwe-24.04, and maybe linux-headers-generic-hwe-24.04-edge the linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic package should be included with the kernel update.

and I still dont understand what you bean by "via an update". It was done precisely as a part of driver installation. When I say - Install soft A for me now, I would expect apt to do that and ONLY that. Why such (unwanted) updates were incuded here? Why now? Why not when I install something else like eg net-tools. I know it is probably ovious to you, but to me its obviously strange and unwanted behavior

"When I say - Install soft A for me now, I would expect apt to do that and ONLY that." Be open to a bit more possibility. Debian-based OS (including Ubuntu) will queue package actions. The new kernel was distributed via the -security channel. Everybody got it. It is quite possible that your system learned of the update, and queued it. When you trigger apt for any install/remove purpose, it will try to run the whole queue.

Allright, but why apt wants to "flush" the queue when I install drivers and not when I install other stuff like lets say apt install net-tools
